# NLog not writing in Asp.Net Web Api App

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I have been trying to implement NLog as a trace writer in an Asp.Net Web Api 2.2 app.  This is my web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
</configSections>
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="c:\file.txt">
<targets>
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/log.txt"/>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile"/>
  </rules>
</targets>
```

During debugging this works fine if I am using IIS Express as the host, but If I set the project to use Local IIS it fails with a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.  I am running VS 2013 as an administrator too.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the user, which is configured in the Local IIS to be used to run the appdomain of your web application, have the sufficient access rights to write to the `${basedir}/Logs` directory.

Please, ensure that you can run this code from your application:

```
File.WriteAllText(
    Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Logs\test.txt"),
    "Some content");
```

When you are able to do this, you'll also would be able to do the logging